# ¿Cómo manipular los datos de un diccionario JSON?

Tags: python, json

Estoy tratando de aprender a manejar con Python las respuestas POST de una aplicación que las devuelve en diccionario JSON.

```
response :
 {'status': 'success', 'response': [{'recipient_id': 'default', 'text': 'Hello! How can I help?'}]}
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener el texto: "Hello! How can I help?" de esta JSON dict? Intenté

```
response_text = json.dumps(response[0].response[0].text)
```

Pero me contesta el terminal :

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'response'
```

Y con

```
response_text = json.dumps(response[0].text)
```

me contesta :

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: No me queda muy claro de que partes por lo que muestran los errores ¿Cuál es la salida de `print(response)`? Prueba  `response_text = response[0]["response"][0]["text"]`

Comment: @FJSevilla
Sí, fue casi eso. `response_text = json.dumps(response[0].get("text","Wait, what did you said?") )` o `response_text = json.dumps(response[0]["text"])`Gracias FJ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"text" no es una clave. Es un String. Entonces :

```
response_text = json.dumps(response[0].get("text","Wait, what did you said?") )
```

o

```
response_text = json.dumps(response[0]["text"])
```

Answer (score 2):

las respuestas post suelen devolver un string, antes de poder manipular el json hay que convertirlos a  json:

```
 json_response = json.loads(response)
 # finalmente accedemos al campo que deseamos 
 text = json_response['response'][0]['text']
```

los que se encuentra dentro de llaves "{....}" son propiedades y para acceder a sus valores se tiene que el nombre de las mismas.

los que se encuentran dentro de corchete "z=[{A},{B},{c}]" son elementos de la lista y para acceder a sus valores se utiliza el indice, por ejemplo para acceder a {B} seria b=z[1]